# vb.net insert error into mysql with comma in field

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

Created a vb.net app that is moving data from Microsoft SQL Server to MySQL.  All my insert functions have worked so far except the following.   It appears that the issue is with a field that has comma's in the text and is causing a problem.

I believe the issue is with the column 'Categories'.  It has values like '11|0,1|0,12|0'.

Are comma needed to be handled in a special way?

Error:
Sql error: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Separator,C_ID,EntryDt,S_ID) VALUES (1,1455090, '11|0,1' at line 1

Code:

```
#Region " InsertTable_Activity "
    Function InsertTable_Activity(ByVal Activity_ID As Integer, _
        ByVal Categories As String, _
        ByVal Separator As String, _
        ByVal C_ID As Integer, _
        ByVal EntryDt As DateTime, _
        ByVal S_ID As Integer, _
         ByVal myCon As MySqlConnection) As String

        Dim sRetVal As String = ""
        Dim sSQL As String = "INSERT INTO CandidateInsertResumeDetailCategories_Activity (Activity_ID,Categories,Separator,C_ID,EntryDt,S_ID) VALUES (?Activity_ID, ?Categories, ?Separator, ?C_ID,?EntryDt,?S_ID)"
        Dim myCmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(sSQL, myCon)
        myCmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.Text
        myCmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("?Activity_ID", MySqlDbType.Int32)).Value = Activity_ID
        myCmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("?Categories", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 500)).Value = Categories
        myCmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("?Separator", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 10)).Value = Separator
        myCmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("?C_ID", MySqlDbType.Int32)).Value = C_ID
        myCmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("?EntryDt", MySqlDbType.DateTime)).Value = EntryDt
        myCmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("?S_ID", MySqlDbType.Int32)).Value = S_ID

        Try
            If myCon.State <> Data.ConnectionState.Open Then
                myCon.Open()
            End If

            myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            myCmd.Dispose()

        Catch sqlEx As MySqlException
            sRetVal = "ERROR: Sql error: " & sqlEx.ToString & vbCrLf & " - SQL used: " & sSQL
        Catch ex As Exception
            sRetVal = "ERROR: Regular error: " & ex.ToString & vbCrLf & " - SQL used: " & sSQL
        Finally
        End Try

        Return sRetVal
    End Function
#End Region
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SEPARATOR` is a reserved keyword, you should escape it with backtick,

```
INSERT INTO CandidateInsertResumeDetailCategories_Activity 
            (Activity_ID, Categories, `Separator`, C_ID, EntryDt, S_ID) 
VALUES .....
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Another word-of-advice is *not to use any names which on the list of reserved keywords*.